# Why is Talia willing to have extramarital sex?

Tags: plot-explanation, prisoners-of-war

In the second season of the Israeli show *Prisoners of War*, after the breakdown of her marriage, Talia goes on a date with her daughter's former therapist (Dr. Ostrovsky) and also has a date and sex once with a man she meets in a yoga class.

That Talia is willing to go on a date with Ostrovsky seems reasonable -- she already knows him, and it's only a date. **But why is she willing to have a short, presumably one-off date and sex casually, with someone from yoga?** Talia spent a lot of time after Nimrod's capture campaigning for his release, so it seems reasonable to conclude that she might be, while not an outright celebrity, someone people might recognize, particularly since Nimrod's return was somewhat recent. Moreover, she should be aware of the bad publicity Nurit got after she gave up on Uri years ago to marry his brother, and similarly, the criticism Nurit later received for leaving Ya'akov (the brother) for Uri after his return.

It's possible I'm not really aware of something: Talia doesn't seem to care as much anymore about giving up her life for Nimrod's cause, and maybe that's enough for her behaviour here. Or maybe for all the attention she's received, it's unlikely that the average person cares enough about her (or alternatively, that the average person would easily recognize her).